# " I would say ... " vs " I think that ... " , are there any differences in meaning or use between saying them

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

Are there any differences in meaning/usage between when NAmE Speakers saying or replying with " I would say ( that ) ... " vs " I think ( that ) ... " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much difference. "I would say that" perhaps suggests a more considered opinion than "I think that" at least for some speakers. But it could be mere style or habit of expression. "I would say" is slightly more formal. But either could be used in place of the other, and context might alter these shades of meaning.

Comment: I see. Tanks a lot! And by the way , would you mind giving me some few other contexts in which they can be used in and how their meaning can exactly change with a different context or perhaps suggest anything  to me that might actually help with gaining more accurate and correct understanding about it?